# Setting a default value for a type (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing type `example_type` with values a,b, and c.

Up until now, there was a nullable column that used the above type. (default value of that column was null)

I am trying to write a migration that should eventually set the default value for that column to be `example_type.c`.

First of all, I executed the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table 
ALTER COLUMN example_column 
SET DATA TYPE example_type;
```

Now I am trying to set the default value of that type to be `c` with:

```
ALTER TYPE example_type 
SET DEFAULT example_type.c;
```

Which fails on `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"`

I looked around [ALTER TYPE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertype.html) and found nothing related to setting a default value.

Is there another way to approach this?

EDIT:

I also tried to set a default value for the column itself with:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table
ALTER COLUMN example_column 
SET DEFAULT example_type.c;
```

which resulted in : `ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`

The type was originally created with:

```
CREATE TYPE example_type AS ENUM('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: You can only set defaults for columns or domains, not for types.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I also tried to set a default for the column itself and it failed for a different reason, see edit.

Comment: Well, as the error message says: a default value must be a constant. You can't reference other columns for defaults.

Comment: meaning there's no way to set a column's default value to a type's value?
The only workaround is putting the actual const value of `example_type.c`?

Comment: A type has no value, so your question doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: it is an enumerated type, does it make more sense?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Ist that an `ENUM` or a composite type? Is `c` a value of an enum or a column of a composite type? A `CREATE TYPE` and `CREATE TABLE` statement would help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added the `CREATE TYPE` query, see edit

Comment: The notation is the issue I think.  AFAIK you specify an enum value as a string literal i.e. `'some enum value'`.  In your case it would be just `'c'`, **not** `example_type.c`.

Comment: @AndriyM that worked.
I was under the wrong impression that I need to reference it from the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to set the default value for an enum type is

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col SET DEFAULT CAST ('c' AS example_type);
```